# JPA persistence UnknownEntity Error when I want to persist entity using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity that I want to persist it to oracle DB . Ive created all interfaces and their related implementations but I get UnknowEntity error. I use springframework 5 and Ive declare service and Dao in xml file. any solution?

I add my service to config.xml but nothing changed!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a legacy configuration version of spring framework. Please check your project directory and find some xml files that entities are declared there. If there is nothing you should create a new one and define persistence-unit in your xml file.
For more information visit [this link](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persistence-xml/#:%7E:text=The%20persistence.,as%20JPA%20provider%20configuration%20properties.)

Comment: I have a persistence.xml file I add my entity class to it and now it works! tnx alot